# Масштабирование спрайтовых изображений

Tags: css, css3

Как быть в ситуации, когда изображение (`background-image`), взятое со спрайта, необходимо уменьшить?

https://jsfiddle.net/t3xad9wx/3/

То есть, существует некий элемент, размеры которого заданы в относительных единицах (`rem`). Этот элемент масштабируется в зависимости от размеров окна. Необходимо, чтобы фоновое изображение внутри него подстраивалось под его размеры. Если бы это было обычное изображение, то `background-size: 100%` решило бы проблему, но так как фоновое изображение задано спрайтом, такой код приводит лишь к тому, что внутри элемента отображается весь фон, а не отдельный спрайт, как ожидается.

Answer (score 2):

как вариант так... я  изменил ответ, вроде все работает или же я не совсем понял чего тебе надо.... мне кажется ты rem путаешь с процентами

```css
#wrapperSpan {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;

  padding: 4px;
}

span {
 
  background-image: url('http://www.quadrathell.cn.ua/_fr/0/1506107.png');
  background-position: 0px -59px;
  margin-top: -47px;
  margin-left: -47px;
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperSpan">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Air, это хороший вариант, но если размеры элемента заданы в `em` (`rem`), то он не подойдет. Требуется именно масштабировать фон, подстраивая под размеры элемента, а здесь фиксированно задается параметр `scale`.

Comment: а примере PX...  минутку я щас подумаю...

Comment: Опиши конкретно  и пример свой измени,  а то у тя в примере одно а ты хочешь другое...  опиши развернутый вопрос... хотя и так вроде у меня работает с rem и em..

Comment: Air, изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, почему элемент, размеры которого заданы в единицах базового шрифта, меняется от размеров окна...

Задай `background-size:calc(x / y * 100%)`, где x - ширина всего фонового изображения в пикселах, y - ширина конкретного спрайта. Ну и `background-position` тоже нужно будет пересчитать пропорционально.